# re-transform existing avatars

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I use [Arc](https://github.com/stavro/arc) to attach an avatar image to a User model:

```
defmodule Abc.User do
  use Abc.Web, :model
  use Arc.Ecto.Schema

  schema "users" do
    field :first_name, :string
    field :last_name, :string
    field :avatar, Abc.Avatar.Type
    [...]
```

I transform a thumbnail from that avatar which I want to change for existing users. I changed the transformation rules and need to re-transform them.

How can I re-transform the avatar of a given User?

Comment: I don't think Arc has any builtin way to do this according to https://github.com/stavro/arc/issues/47.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way to do this would be to have the original image as one of the attachment versions for `Abc.Avatar` and use arc_ecto's `cast_attachments` to reupload that image when you make changes and want to retransform the other versions.

In `avatar.ex` you would have an `:original` version without transformations.

```
defmodule Abc.Avatar do
  use Arc.Definition
  use Arc.Ecto.Definition
  @versions [:original, :thumb]
  ...
  # You specify transformations for :thumb but not for :original
  def transform(:thumb, _) do
    # Your transformation
  end
  ...
end
```

Then in `user.ex` define a `changeset` to upload the avatar. If you use s3 you need to send the `allow_paths: true` to `cast_attachments`, so that you can upload the image by sending its url.

```
def update_avatar(user, params) do
  user
  |> cast_attachments(params, [:avatar], allow_paths: true)
end
```

Finally define a method somewhere that gets the original avatar url (or local path) and passes it to `update_avatar` and updates the database (could be in the same user module or some extra helper module).

```
def retransform_avatar(user) do
  url = Abc.Avatar.url({user.avatar, user}, :original)

  Abc.User.update_avatar(user, %{avatar: url}) |> Abc.Repo.update()
end
```

If you want to reprocess all images at once you could do something like:

```
Abc.Repo.all(Abc.User) |> Enum.each(fn u -> retransform_avatar(u) end)
```